# asp.net core - How to serve static file with no extension

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core hapily serves up files from the `wwwroot` folder based on the mime type of the file. But how do I get it serve up a file with no extension?

As an example, Apple require that you have an endpoint in your app `/apple-app-site-association` for some app-intergration. If you add a text file called apple-app-site-association into your wwwroot it won't work.

Some things I've tried:

1) Provide a mapping for when there's no extension:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[""] = "text/plain";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
```

2) Adding an app rewrite:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRewrite("^apple-app-site-association","/apple-app-site-association.txt", false)
```

Neither work, the only thing that does work is a `.AddRedirect` which I'd rather not use if possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rather than fighting with static files, I think you'd be better off just creating a controller for it:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;

namespace MyApp.Controllers {
    [Route("apple-app-site-association")]
    public class AppleController : Controller {
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public AppleController(IHostingEnvironment environment) {
            _hostingEnvironment = environment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
            return Content(
                await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "apple-app-site-association")),
                "text/plain"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes your `apple-app-site-association` file is in your wwwroot folder.

Comment: Lol, this is pretty much exactly what I gave up and reverted to - although it feels somewhat wrong, but it does work!

Comment: If it's stupid but it works, then it ain't stupid! :)

Comment: Like this you don't event need an actual file in the wwwroot. I've had the same problem with the Apple file - I've put the credentials into appsettings and generated json in code.

Answer (score 39):

Adding an alternative solution. You have to set ServeUnknownFileTypes to true and after that set the default content type.

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
            DefaultContentType = "text/plain"
        });
```

Comment: Downvoting because this adds a security risk as explained in the ASP Core docs. The accepted answer is the best way to "whitelist" files to be served without opening up all file types.

Comment: If you are concerned about security you can either reduce the scope of the served file with this option with a specific PhysicalFileProvider, or implement your own IFileProvider as the StaticFileOptions.FileProvider property.

Comment: Warning

Enabling ServeUnknownFileTypes is a security risk. It's disabled by default, and its use is discouraged.

Comment: Just what I needed thanks.  This is development work, i dont need to worry about deep security.

If you want your default to be binary files use "application/octet-stream"

Comment: The Core docs don't actually explain how it's a security risk, they just state it. On its own I don't see how it's a risk.

Answer (score 8):

An easier option may be to put a file with a proper extension on the server, and then use URL rewrite as follows.

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite("(.*)/apple-app-site-association", "$1/apple-app-site-association.json", true));
```

Comment: Best answer! No security risks like allowing all unknown static filetypes and no overhead by creating a controller for returning a simple json file.

Comment: This somehow didn't work for me in .NET 6. I had to use `app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("^apple-app-site-association$", "/apple-app-site-association.json", true));`

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is to add the *apple-app-site-association* file in a *.well-known* folder in the root folder of the application as described here: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains] and then allow access to it from your code,  like this (Startup.cs):

```html
 // to allow access to apple-app-site-association file
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @".well-known")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
    DefaultContentType = "application/json",
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
});
```

Tested in AWS Serverless Application (.NET Core 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

AspNetCore does not serve unknown file types for security reasons, but it should generally be safe to do for files in the `.well-known` folder.

The problem is that Apple requires the correct MIME type for files without extensions, so we must explicitly configure those.

**Solution**

1. Allow serving unknown file types (no extension) from `.well-known` folder.
2. Add files to `wwwroot/.well-known` folder.
3. Add a custom `IContentTypeProvider` to map filenames to MIME type, such as `apple-app-site-association` file name to `application/json` MIME type.

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", ".well-known")),
    RequestPath = "/.well-known",
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    ContentTypeProvider = new CustomWellKnownFileContentTypeProvider(),
});
```

**CustomWellKnownFileContentTypeProvider.cs**

```
/// <summary>
///     Custom file extension content type provider for serving certain extension-less files in .well-known folder.
///     <list type="bullet">
///         <item>apple-app-site-association - application/json - Apple Universal Link association</item>
///     </list>
/// </summary>
public class CustomWellKnownFileContentTypeProvider : IContentTypeProvider
{
    private readonly FileExtensionContentTypeProvider _defaultProvider = new();

    public bool TryGetContentType(string subpath, out string contentType)
    {
        // Custom handling of files without file extensions.

        // Apple Universal Link association, requires the correct MIME type set.
        if (subpath.EndsWith("apple-app-site-association", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            contentType = "application/json";
            return true;
        }

        // Fallback to default provider, based on file extension.
        if (_defaultProvider.TryGetContentType(subpath, out string? extContentType))
        {
            contentType = extContentType;
            return true;
        }

        contentType = string.Empty;
        return false;
    }
}
```