# Importing Typescript modules in ASP.NET Core 2.2 app

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to perform a simple Import of one Typescript file into another Typescript file within an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application (Visual Studio 2019).  I am not using any other framework such as Angular. I'm running into problems with not being able to find the correct path for the Module file at runtime.

I have 2 simple Typescript files which I've placed into a subfolder "Typescript" - they're named 'MyTSModule.ts' and 'AnotherTSModule.ts'(screenshot of Solution Explorer below).  The first Typescript Module contains a single function which references a Property in the second Typescript Module.

Ultimately, I want to execute the function in the first Typescript module within an HTML Script tag.   The code for these files is below, including 'tsconfig.json'.

#### tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

#### MyTSModule.ts file

```
import { anotherTSMessage } from "../Typescript/AnotherTSModule";

export function SayHelloFromAnotherTSModule() {
    alert(anotherTSMessage);
```

}

#### AnotherTSModule.ts file

```
export const anotherTSMessage = "This message is from a second TS Module";
```

#### Inside an CSHTML page

```
 <script type="module">

        import { SayHelloFromAnotherTSModule } from './js/MyTSModule.js';

        $(document).ready(function () {

            alert(SayHelloFromAnotherTSModule());

        });

    </script>
```

In the Output window, I'm getting a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http://localhost:51711/Typescript/AnotherTSModule]" error.  I think the path is wrong but how do I fix this?  Thanks.

Screen shot of Solution Explorer...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing same issue. The problem is, you are requesting `http://localhost:51711/Typescript/AnotherTSModule` while file is `http://localhost:51711/Typescript/AnotherTSModule.js`.

There are number ways to fix it.

You can try to make kernel server serve files without extension, like answered here [asp.net core - How to serve static file with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769310/asp-net-core-how-to-serve-static-file-with-no-extension)  , but I had no luck with it.

You can add '.js' part to your import lines of code, and make it look like that:

```
import { anotherTSMessage } from "../Typescript/AnotherTSModule.js";
```

But if you need it in real project, I would recommend using webpack.

You can also serve your files from server, that doesnt have problem serving files with no extension, nginx, for example.